# How can I delete hidden folders with Python?

Tags: python, file, operating-system, shutil

I need to delete `.git` hidden folder with python for a project. I have a function to do that but it does not work. :(

```
def delete_hidden_files(folder_path):
    try:
        # Gets the list of files in the folder
        file_list = os.listdir(folder_path)

        # Loop to delete each one
        for file_name in file_list:
            file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, file_name)
            if os.path.isfile(file_path):
                if file_name.startswith('.'):  # For Unix (macOS, Linux)
                    os.remove(file_path)
                    print(f"Archivo oculto eliminado: {file_path}")
                elif os.name == 'nt' and os.path.isfile(file_path) and (os.stat(file_path).st_file_attributes & 2): # For Windows
                    os.remove(file_path)
                    print(f"Archivo oculto eliminado: {file_path}")
                else:
                    shutil.rmtree(folder_path, ignore_errors=True)

        print("Todos los archivos ocultos han sido eliminados exitosamente.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Se produjo un error: {str(e)}")
```

I tried what I wrote before, and I expect that my code delete all files.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are using os.path.isfile(file_path) but .git is a folder, then you need to check the condition with os.path.isdir(file_path) and use os. rmdir() instead of os.remove().

I hope I have helped you

EDIT:

```
import os, shutil
def delete_hidden_files(folder_path):
    try:
        # Gets the list of files in the folder
        file_list = os.listdir(folder_path)
        # Loop to delete each one
        for file_name in file_list:
            file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, file_name)
            if os.path.isdir(file_path):
                if file_name.startswith('.'):  # For Unix (macOS, Linux)
                    os.rmdir(file_path)
                    print(f"Carpeta oculta eliminado: {file_path}")
                elif os.name == 'nt' and os.path.isfile(file_path) and (os.stat(file_path).st_file_attributes & 2): # For Windows
                    os.remove(file_path)
                    print(f"Archivo oculto eliminado: {file_path}")
                else:
                    print(f"Archivo oculto eliminado: {folder_path}")
                    shutil.rmtree(folder_path, ignore_errors=True)

        print("Todos los archivos ocultos han sido eliminados exitosamente.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Se produjo un error: {str(e)}")

delete_hidden_files('.')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it still not deleting .git folder

Comment: I've edited the answer with the rmdir() code

Comment: The .git folder stills here. Thanks again for the answer.

Comment: I'm using this snippet and it works for me, take care about ('.') path

Comment: I'm using linux maybe is a bit different on windows

Comment: It still not working, I have to find another way, I think that instead of cloning I have to download, maybe without the git folder, anyway thanks.

Comment: If you can provide me the call of the method and an snapshot of your directories I can try to help you. 

In my case I had a directory /test where I run delete_hidden_files('.'), inside that directory I only had a directory called .git